# How many locations are there in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How many unique locations are there in Minecraft? The Nether is one. The outside world is 2 and the place where the ender dragon is is 3. Are there any more special locations? I'm not talking about biomes I'm talking about areas where you need to teleport to go there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These "locations" are called "dimensions".

This is it, three of them - Overworld, Nether and the End. Mods add more, of course, such as the Aether.

Comment: What is the Aether?

Comment: @YoungGuilo Link: http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Mods/The_Aether

Answer (score 2):

From the Minecraft Wiki: There are currently 3 dimensions: The Overworld (the "normal" gameworld), The Nether (a "hell" dimension), and The End (a sparse floating island, home to the Enderdragon). All three are surrounded by The Void. Other dimensions can be added by Mods.

Answer (score -2):

There are 4 dimensions in minecraft. The names are The Overworld,The Nether,The End and The Aether. Some people havent heard of the Aether you can buy it in a mod. Some people say theres a TNT dimension but thats just hogwash

Comment: Buy? You mean *install*?